# How to make a POST HTTPS request from Firebase Cloud Functions using node-fetch

Tags: post, google-cloud-functions, fetch

I am trying to make POST requests to a third party API from a Firebase Cloud Function using NODE-FETCH but only getting a 400 error.

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad request.","code":"error"}]}
```

This is my code:

```
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

exports.createPowerPayTransaction = onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const raw = {
    external_id: "123",
    callback_url: "https://pagala.link/powerpay/DANSLKNALKNKALXAkXM",
    values: {
      merchant_id: "6RCWEQ81WHAS",
      currency: "PEN",
      document_number: "10060436",
      document_type: "DNI",
      first_name: "John",
      last_name: "Doe",
      email: "jdoe@mail.com",
      country_code: "+01",
      phone_number: "999999999",
      payment_concept: "Test",
      channel: "In store",
    },
    amount: "450.22",
  };

  const url = "https://api.powerpay.pe/api/merchant-transactions/";

  const myHeaders = new Headers();

  myHeaders.append(
    "Authorization",
    "<% MY TOKEN %>"
  );
  myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: myHeaders,
    body: JSON.stringify(raw),
    redirect: "follow",
  };

  const fetchFromURL = async () =>
    await (await fetch(url, requestOptions)).json();

  fetchFromURL().then((data) => {
    res.send(data);
    res.end();
  });
});
```

When I do res.send(requestOptions) to debug, the body apparently it is well formed. However the header appears to be empty

```
{"external_id":"123","callback_url":"https://pagala.link/powerpay/DANSLKNALKNKALXAkXM","values":{"merchant_id":"6RCWEQ81WHAS","currency":"PEN","document_number":"10060436","document_type":"DNI","first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","email":"jdoe@mail.com","country_code":"+01","phone_number":"999999999","payment_concept":"Test","channel":"In store"},"amount":"450.22"}
```

When trying almos an identical request from the from end I got a CORS error, but no a 400 error. The API only works host to host. That is why I tried to move the request to a Cloud Function.

Also an almos identical request from a PHP backend works fine.

What can it be wrong?